# detect a HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden error with PHP or when a website doesnt allow downloading of their images

Tags: php, validation, httprequest, http-status-code-403, imagecreatefrompng

part of my website allows users to enter a URL and the image from that URL is copied and saved.

The other day i had this issue occur:

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(http://preview.netcarshow.com/Ford-Focus_RS500-2011-hd.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
```

Upon research, it was determined that this issue was because the given website did not allow images to be downloaded from their server.

I am working on my validation script, and if this occurs, i want to give some feedback to the user.

How can i detect this issue in PHP? e.g.

```
if (NO DOWNLOAD FROM SERVER ERROR) {
    $return['imageDownloadError'];
}
```

Just a side question, whats the term called when you write a piece of code in plain english? and not in code?

Thanks! Craig

Comment: Code in plain english could be called "pseudo-code".

Comment: I’d use a more sophisticated means of getting the image data, that gives you a little more error control (cURL, file_get_contents with context), and if you have gotten actual image data via that, feed it to `imagecreatefromstring` to generate the image object to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing something like the following:

- try with "imagecreatefromjpeg"
- if the returned variable === FALSE then check why with cURL using "curl_errno".

e.g.

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)){
  echo curl_error($ch);
}
```